# Can someone check if I'm determine the the correct run time, please

Tags: algorithm, runtime, big-o

In my homework, I was asked to determine the big O run time of the following method by counting the approximate number of operations it performs. I'm not very sure about my answer, can someone check if I'm doing it correctly?
[image]

Comment: You give those figures without any explanation, we can't check your work. And it looks weird that the constant c only appears in the innermost instruction.

Comment: "multiply loops together" is not a valid method to get an accurate bound, although it often works in simple cases which is why you see lots of people using it. Yves' answer provides a valid method.

Answer (score 0):

The inner loop (`while`) is executed `O(Log(i))` times, because `j`, initialized to `i`, is halved as many times as possible, and the loop body takes constant time.

As this loop in executed for `i` in range `[0,n)`, the total running time is `O(ΣLog(i))` = `O(Log(n!))` = `O(n Log(n))`. (The summation is on `i` from `0` to `n-1`, and the final expression is drawn from the Stirling's formula.

It is unnecessary to establish a detailed account of all instructions.

Comment: Thank you for the input!
The while loop is inside the for loop, since the for loop executes (n) times, and the while loop itself executes (log n) times, aren't we suppose to multiply them together? That's how I get (n log n).

Comment: @VictoriaM.: no the while loop does not execute log(n) times. Take some time to read my answer.